# Sanity GROQ - Query an array of objects

Tags: next.js, sanity, groq

I'm trying to learn Sanity and I'm stuck in trying to fetch from an array of an objects with multiple strings.

Thank you so much!

**Schema**:

```
 {
        name: "testArray",
        title: "Test Array",
        type: "array",
        of: [
            {
                name: "field",
                type: "object",
                title: "Field",
                fields: [
                    {
                        name: "firstField",
                        type: "string",
                        title: "First String"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "secondField",
                        type: "string",
                        title: "Second String"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
```

**Query**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`->` is a de-referencing operator. We use it only if any of our field is referencing to some document in the current dataset, and we are asking sanity to fetch the referenced document data for us.

In your schema, the `testArray` field is not referencing to any document, so I dont think you should use `->`.
I believe the below code should work fine:

```
*[_type == "<schema_name>"] {
  title,
  testArray
}
```